# Are compilers not allowed to assume const-ref parameters will stay const?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

For example:

https://godbolt.org/g/5eUkrx

```
void f(const int&);

void g1() {
    const int i = 42;

    if (i == 42) f(i);
    if (i == 42) f(i);
}

void g2() {
    int i = 42;

    if (i == 42) f(i);
    if (i == 42) f(i);
}
```

It seems like "f" mutating its argument should be UB, and therefore compilers should be allowed to assume it doesn't happen and optimize accordingly. Yet these two functions will produce different assembly.

I don't have a copy of the standard. Is this not guaranteed?

Comment: `const_cast` ruins everything

Comment: For future use: [A link to a draft of the the standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/)

Comment: It's not `UB` to modify something that was passed by `const` reference if it was originally mutable, but it would be *very* surprising to the user. You would essentially be lying on purpose to your users.

Comment: @JVApen: But isn't `const_cast<>` an "at your own risk" kind of a thing?

Comment: I'm not arguing you should write it, I rather see it as UB. For the details, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49117523/2466431

Comment: @Rakete1111 not good enough. The function might not modify that particular object, but the behaviour of the function can depend on what object is being referred to.

Comment: @einpoklum It is, but compiler has to assume the worst - that a given function modifies a value behind a const reference, unfortunately.

Comment: @user2079303 Shoot :(

Comment: This is frustrating indeed!

Answer (score 14):

It's perfectly fine according to the standard to cast a pointer-to-const to pointer-to-non-const in C++ and then modify it (albeit it is confusing), as long the value the pointer points to wasn't declared as `const`. In fact, C++ provides a keyword to do such a cast, `const_cast`.

For instance, this is fine.

```
int a = 2;
const int* b = &a;
*const_cast<int*>(b) = 4;
```

But this isn't as a memory location to which pointer points to is `const`.

```
const int a = 2;
const int* b = &a;
*const_cast<int*>(b) = 4;
```

Compiler in your example has to assume that a called function could possibly do that as it knows nothing about it, and prepare for such a situation.

Comment: Re: "cast a const pointer" -- be careful with wording here: there are two objects involved, the pointer and the thing it points at. A const pointer is a pointer that is const; it doesn't have to point at a const object. The question here is about modifying the object, not the pointer. The sense of this answer is right, but it's talking about a pointer to const, not a const pointer.

Comment: @PeteBecker Corrected.

Comment: Yes, this change fixes the problem. I'll leave the comment, since it's a common confusion.

Answer (score 6):

> It seems like "f" mutating its argument should be UB

It is not, as long as it was not `const` when you passed it to the function.  It is only UB to modify something that was `const` to begin with.  So, `f` could modify `i` and you have to plan accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

A `const` ref may alias the same memory as a non-`const` variable that's modified in another thread.  An interesting talk where this comes up (by an LLVM/Clang developer) is available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FnGCDLhaxKU

Comment: You are only allowed to modify the other variable in another thread when using `std::atomic`

Comment: @JVApen Modification from multiple threads is not limited to `std::atomic`.

Comment: Agreed, although Stephen doesn't mention any synchronization

Answer (score 2):

## No

```
void foo( int const& x ) {
  const_cast<int&>(x) = 7;
}
```

this is legal C++.

Invoking it with a reference to an *actual* `const int` results in undefined behavior.

```
int x =42;
foo(x);
std::cout << x << "\n";
```

this must print `"7\n"`.

```
int const x = 42;
f(x);
```

this program exhibits undefined behavior.

```
void g1() {
  const int i = 42;

  if (i == 42) f(i);
  if (i == 42) f(i);
}
```

the compiler *may assume* `i==42` is `true` regardless of what `f` does.  There is no way defined in C++ to make a value read through `i` anything other than `42`.

```
void g2() {
  int i = 42;
  if (i == 42) f(i);
  if (i == 42) f(i);
}
```

the compiler *must* check if `i==42` still after the call to `f(const int&)` if it cannot examine the code within `f(const int&)` (since it is defined and valid, even if surprising, behavior for `f()` to change `i`, and the compiler must respect this possibility).  It can, however, optimize the *first* `i==42` to `true`, as there is no defined way for `i` to be changed.

```
void g3() {
  int j =34;
  int i = 42;
  f(j);
  if (i == 42) f(i);
  if (i == 42) f(i);
}
```

here, even though you could imagine that `f` takes the address of `j`, finds `i` next to it, then modified `i`, that is not defined behavior.  There remains no way within the bounds of the standard to modify `i` between initialization and the first `i==42` check.

A lot of the reachability rules of C++ are about the compiler being permitted to assume that variables are only modified in certain code, and cannot be modified in others.

Going deeper down the rabbit hole:

```
struct foo {
  int arr[3]={1,2,3};
  int x = 42;
};
```

here:

```
foo bob;

f(bob.arr[0]);
```

this call to `f` *can* modify all of `bob.arr[0]`, `bob.arr[1]` and `bob.arr[2]`, but it *cannot* modify `bob.x`.  There is no way under the standard to get from an element of an array to a different member of the struct containing the array.

---

Note that code modifying things through `const&` is extremely dangerous and a bad plan.  But C++ allows it.

Comment: Why _must_ the compiler check that i == 42 after the first call? Is that explicitly required by the standard?

Comment: @einpoklum it must behave as if it checked?  I mean it could set a cpu register that raises an interrupt if data at the location of i is written to then assume if said interrupt is not raised it wasn't changed, or prove f willnot change its argument some other way, but that is just noise.

Comment: > const_cast<int&>(x) = 7; this is legal C++. < I guess my follow-up question is: Why? Was it for C compatibility? Or is there some scenario where it's desirable for this to be legal?

Comment: @Yakk: But, again, why must it? Will it be breaking the standard if it assumed i is 42?

Comment: @einpoklum If `i` is not `42` and the change was done through behavior defined by the standard, then assuming `i` is `42` is in violation of the standard?  The standard describes the behavior of an abstract machine; if in that machine `i` is not `42`, having the compiled code disagree with the abstract machine's choice of branch is not what the standard says the compiled code is supposed to do?

Comment: @JeffM Believe it or not there are edge cases where de-`const`ing makes sense. It's a last resort, and some of these cases have been resolved with the addition of [the `mutable` qualifier.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv)

Comment: @Yakk: So the machine model requires respecting changes via const_cast to non-const data passed via const references?

Comment: @einpoklum Yes.  The reference produced by `const_cast` is a valid reference and anything you could do with a reference you can do with it (so long as the data isn't actually const).

Comment: @Yakk: Edited the answer in accordance with your latest answer to make that point come across clearer and more explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If `f()` has no side effect you could declare it with `__attribute__((const))`:

```
int f(const int&) __attribute__((const));
```

Note that it doesn't make sense for a `const` function to return `void`, so I changed it to `int`; and to avoid the compiler from optimising away the whole function call I assigned to an `extern`:

```
int f(const int&) __attribute__((const));

extern int j;

void g1() {
    const int i = 42;

    if (i == 42) j = f(i);
    if (i == 42) j = f(i);
}

void g2() {
    int i = 42;

    if (i == 42) j = f(i);
    if (i == 42) j = f(i);
}
```

Now both `g1()` and `g2()` compile to a single call to `f()`.

Comment: Thanks. This along with attribute pure answers another and related question I had https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49227571/are-there-extensions-to-let-optimizers-assume-const-ref-parameters-will-stay-con  If you add this answer there, I can reward you with internet points.