# Are there extensions to let optimizers assume const-ref parameters will stay const?

Tags: c++

Related to my former question: [Are compilers not allowed to assume const-ref parameters will stay const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49117489/are-compilers-not-allowed-to-assume-const-ref-parameters-will-stay-const)

My new question is: Is there compiler-specific, non-standard extensions or syntax to tell GCC/Clang/MSVC that an object is not writable? For example, here's some fake-ish code I'd like to be able to write:

```
void f(const int& i) {

    // At this point, compiler doesn't know if "i" can be mutated or not,
    // so it assumes it can

    // Fake-ish -- compiler now assumes "i" cannot be mutated and optimizes accordingly
    __assume(readonly i);

    // ...

}
```

Comment: You might be able to do it with [`__restrict`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Restricted-Pointers.html).

Comment: Meh, it is the job of the optimizer to figure this out.  If it cannot inline f() because it is too beefy then it just doesn't matter much anymore.  Be sure to measure it.

Comment: @user2357112 \_\_restrict doesn't seem to achieve the desired effect. https://godbolt.org/g/xvsUaB

Comment: can you explain why you want to do this? It seems like a very bad idea to make any assumptions about how the compiler may or may not optimize your code; that's the reason we write in higher level languages.

Comment: You can still make local const copy. then that copy cannot be modified.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `i` is supposed to stay const for the whole function, and `f()` has no side effects, you could declare it with `__attribute__((pure))`:

```
int f(const int&) __attribute__((pure));
```

Note that it doesn't make sense for a `pure` function to return `void`, so I changed it to `int`.

While this does not affect how `f()` is compiled, it does affect the functions calling it (check it on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/ATxjHB)):

```
#include <iostream>

int f(const int& i) __attribute__((pure));

int main() {
    int i = 40;
    f(i);
    if (i != 40) {
        std::cout << "not 40" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here `__attribute__((pure))` tells the compiler that `f()` will not change `i`, so the compiler will not generate the call to `std::cout << ...`.

Without `__attribute__((pure))`,  even if `f()` is declared to take a `const int& i` parameter, the compiler has to assume that the value of `i` may change, and generate the `if` and the call to `std::cout << ...` .

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of non-standard ways to permit the compiler to assume immutability, but if I read the standard correctly, I think there is a standard way to do so (adapted from your other question):

```
void f(const int&);

struct ImmutableInt {
    // it is UB to change val, because it is itself const
    // not just a const reference
    const int val;    
};

void g3(const ImmutableInt & i) {
    if (i.val == 42) f(i.val);
    if (i.val == 42) f(i.val); // the compiler could assume i.val has not changed
}
```

The problem is, currently the compilers I [checked](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'void+f(const+int%26)%3B%0A%0Astruct+ImmutableInt+%7B%0A++++const+int+i%3B++++%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Avoid+g3(const+ImmutableInt+%26+i)+%7B%0A++++if+(i.i+%3D%3D+42)+f(i.i)%3B%0A++++if+(i.i+%3D%3D+42)+f(i.i)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) do not make use of this knowledge to actually omit reloading the value.

I do not think there are any fundamental problems with this, because clang uses similar and more complicated reasoning about the virtual table pointer to achieve [devirtualization](http://blog.llvm.org/2017/03/devirtualization-in-llvm-and-clang.html). This reasoning is somewhat more complicated because the vptr will change during construction and is therefore not entirely const. The llvm metadata used for this is called invariant.group, but I do not know if you can set it yourself in C++.

Comment: @Jarod42: Changing a variable declared as const is undefined behaviour, so the compiler may assume it does not happen. This has nothing to do with threads.

Comment: Didn't see the const in `ImmutableInt`, sorry.